# Cantor Function Continuity

Tags: calculus, functions, intuition

I am interested in knowing more about the continuity of the Cantor Function. I have read that the function is discontinuous precisely at the points of the Cantor Set and it is continuous everywhere else.

Can anyone please elaborate on why exactly this is true?

Comment: It is not. ${}$

Comment: Ok, can you explain what is actually true about the continuity of the Cantor Function then?

Comment: You can get a proof from scratch that the Cantor function is continuous pretty easily just by using the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The Cantor function $\phi:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ is monotone non-decreasing. Hence, there are at worst countably many jump discontinuities. However,  $\phi$ is surjective and $\phi([0,1]) = [0,1]$.

Comment: Also for $x \in C$ if $|y-x|< 3^{-n}$ then $|\phi(y) - \phi(x)| < 2^{-n}.$